# Yii 2: useles query performed

Tags: yii2

I've a datasheet table with a product_id pointing to product.id

In ProductQuery, extending ActiveQuery, I created these functions

```
public function all($db = null)
{
    return parent::all($db);
}

public function not_g00()
{
    $this->andWhere('category_code <> "G00"');
    return $this;
}


public function without_datasheet()
{
    $this->joinWith('datasheet');
    $this->andWhere(['{{%datasheet}}.id'=> null]);
    return $this;
}

public function from_newest()
{
    $this->addOrderBy(['created_on' => SORT_DESC]);
    return $this;
}
```

While find is actually overridden into Product class

```
public static function find()
{
    return new \frontend\models\query\ProductQuery(get_called_class());
}
```

And I use as :

```
$products_without_datasheet = Product::find()
        ->not_g00()
        ->without_datasheet()
        ->from_newest()
        ->all();
```

the results is a first query, simply perfect:

```
SELECT `tbl_product`.* FROM `tbl_product` LEFT JOIN `tbl_datasheet` 
ON `tbl_product`.`id` = `tbl_datasheet`.`product_id`
WHERE (category_code <> "G00") AND (`tbl_datasheet`.id IS NULL) 
ORDER BY `created_on` DESC
```

But debug log shows that a SECOND query is executed AFTER this.

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_datasheet` WHERE `product_id` IN (7541, 7929,... )
```

The debug show me that this query is called by `datasheet::find()->all()... but why?!`, called by the all() of

```
$products_without_datasheet = Product::find()
        ->not_g00()
        ->without_datasheet()
        ->from_newest()
        ->all();
```

Why? What am I doing wrong? Why is it performing 2 query when the first one is already perfect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `$this->joinWith('datasheet');`, if you don't want to fetch related datasheets you should simply use `$this->joinWith('datasheet', false);`

About `joinWith()` :

> If the $eagerLoading parameter is true, the method will also eager
>   loading the specified relations, which is equivalent to calling with()
>   using the specified relations.

Read more about [`joinWith()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#joinWith()-detail).